# How is this offtopic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Can some explain how [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120705/how-to-call-in-sick) is off topic?

It may not be the best worded question in the world and it may be lacking some detail, but I fail to see how asking the appropriate protocol for calling (or emailing) in sick when you start work before your boss is off topic.

Comment: What industry does the OP work in (not everyone is software eng, protocol here changes based on industry)? What does their boss prefer? What country are they in? Are they part of a union? How time sensitive is it that the OP or their boss know they are not being sick? All of these, among other unanswered questions, would be required for a meaningful answer to the question they are asking.

Comment: I agree, but again, not off topic

Comment: Keep in mind that being on "hold" doesn't directly mean "off topic" - questions which need more information _should_ be put on hold until the relevant information is added. Questions can be on hold for reasons related to topicality as well as what information is present in the question (or not present).

Comment: @ElysianFields I understand that, but this question was put on hold as off topic

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the "correct" procedure for reporting in sick is usually specified by the company and should be described in the contract or company handbook. Or at the very least agreed between a manager and their direct reports.

In my career I've encounterd:

- Call this automated HR voicemail box before 8:30, no other methods acceptable
- Contact your manager however you want
- Just don't turn up and we'll assume you are sick
- Email HR
- Email only
- Manage it yourself but don't take the mickey

and while each would have been the correct answer to the question - it would only have applied to companies with that process or a compatible one.

A question around "I can't follow the procedure/can't find out the procedure because of *x*, what is the best alternate to choose in the absence of other info" would be on topic possibly, but a question asking for "the" correct way is just too company specific.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a great answer to OP's question.

Comment: I agree completely, but it's not offtopic

Comment: @SaggingRufus You agree what? That the correct procedure will be different for every company? Then how can you think it's still on-topic? The off-topic reason explicitly states,  "*Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors.*"